# Unable to Play youtube videos in Microsoft Adaptive card

Tags: json, youtube, botframework, adaptive-cards, video-player

I have requirement to play any mp4 video inside adaptive card. I referred from the below website on how to include media in adaptive cards:

https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Media.html

Example video in the above link works perfectly fine . But if I replace the video URL with any other youtube or mp4 video URL link then it does not play that video. Below is the card that I have created.

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "version": "1.3",
  "fallbackText": "This card requires Media to be viewed. Ask your platform to update to Adaptive Cards v1.1 for this and more!",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "Media",
            "poster": "https://adaptivecards.io/content/poster-video.png",
            "sources": [
                {
                    "mimeType": "video/mp4",
                    "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pxhqeHFLAF0"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Please help me on how to play a youtube video in adaptive cards.

Comment: as per my understanding it will support only mp4, The video that you are using just a link without extension..

Comment: What channel are you using? And can you provide an example of an mp4 file URL (not a YouTube URL) that you've tried? (Since there are multiple other people in this thread, you will need to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.)

Comment: @Delaney . I want to play youtube video in an adptive card. Certainly youtube  video link is not a link to the file. It is just URL link. The link that I am trying to play is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pxhqeHFLAF0

Comment: @RajeeshMenoth . I think you are right. But how to play youtube videos in adaptive cards is the question?

Comment: @user3553913 it's possible but running in the same chat at least front-end work is required. If Kyle Delaney have any direct implementation then it should be fine. otherwise i will share u what we have done in the web chat side.

Comment: @user3553913 - You haven't answered either of my questions. By asking an Adaptive Card question you're asking a UI question and therefore it's important for us to know what channel you're using. Also, you said "But if I replace the video URL with any other youtube or mp4 video URL link then it does not play that video." You're only showing us YouTube URL links. What's an example of an mp4 video URL link you've tried?

Comment: @user3553913 - Are you still working on this?

Comment: @Delaney - I am working on it. Sorry I did not see your comment. To answer your questions, I am using bot framework webchat for adaptive card design. I want to play youtube videos in the media block. 
Regarding what I said - I mean for few of the urls with .mp4 it works. But it does not work for youtube videos and few of the .mp4 videos. May be some formatting issue with videos. But how can I play youtube videos in the adaptive cards is the question

Comment: @user3553913 - Is my answer acceptable?

Comment: @user3553913 do you find way to play video from youtube?

Comment: @Damian only video files with .mp4 extension can be played

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that Web Chat does support YouTube URL's in video attachments. You can see an example of such an attachment [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/2697#issuecomment-563507326). However, if you try to use your particular YouTube URL then you'll just be redirected to YouTube:

[image: Web Chat]

When it comes to Adaptive Cards, you won't be able to use YouTube URL's. You can submit Adaptive Cards feature requests here: https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues/new/choose

Comment: YouTube works fine for more in various host apps in the Designer, but not with the JS library: `"adaptivecards": "2.11.1". I'm using ```json
{
  "type": "Media",
  "sources": [
    {
      "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ"
    }
  ]
}
```